# CUDA : Is it normal to GPU is slow(need more time) when the program starts?

Tags: opencv, cuda, gpgpu

I am using CUDA for image processing.

My program gets a video and synthesis some image from input video and saves a video with new images.

This program was CPU-only first and I'm upgrading its speed with CUDA.

By the way, I found something strange result when I compared process speed.

CPU needs around 75 ms to run some function of program and the time doesn't fluctuating too much. ( around 3 ms )

But, I found GPU needs extremely much more time when it works for the first frame.

GPU needs 1 ms for that function usually, but needs 500 ms when it works for the first frame.

Is this normal?

Of course, tasks for checking time is same for each frame.

Data allocation for GPU is performed for each frame, not only for the first frame.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes this is normal

Comment: initialization is always more expensive. But for nvidia GPUs (and maybe other devices) there's one more thing. You can either precompile your program for specific devices (like a fixed chipset) or you can compile it without device information and let your host compile the gpu code during runtime for that specific hardware. That's called Just-in-Time compilation (JIT). If you program is currently using JIT, you can reduce the initial frame runtime by switching to precompiling for your target hardware.

Comment: it is explained here in chapter "Compilation for Different NVIDIA* Platforms ": https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/dbc/cuda_intro.html

Comment: You can probably avoid most of it by calling some CUDA API functions before the API calls for the first frame. See the linked duplicate for more information

Comment: Thank you, both of you!